# why there is difference between the two commands

Tags: sorting, unique

I was trying to filter out some stuff and using a long linux command with two differences. In the first case, i have used

```
cat test.txt | sort | uniq -c | wc -l
```

In the second case, I have used
without sorting

```
cat test.txt | uniq -c | wc -l
```

I am wondering why there is a difference in the number of lines? Can someone please explain this?

Thanks
Upendra

Comment: `uniq` assumes that the input is sorted.

Answer (score 0):

`uniq` replaces multiple consecutive occurrences of a line with one line; if they're not consecutive, they're not replaced.  For example, consider input:

```
word
word
other
word
word
```

which `uniq` will turn into:

```
word
other
word
```

Now, when you `sort` first, then the original input becomes:

```
other
word
word
word
word
```

and then `uniq`, which now has all `word`s consecutively, will output:

```
other
word
```

Comment: Great thanks. How do i get the uniq values even when they are not consecutive. My main purpose is to keep the order as it is and so don't want to sort but still wants to get the uniq values.

Comment: ... you'll do it a tool other than `uniq`! :-)  That question should be posted as a new question if you want it to gain appropriate attention from others.  I'm only able to answer your first question at this point.

Answer (score 0):

As Richard described about the uniq work principle, it depends on the usage.

However it should work fine with your first command only,anyhow ur not altering the test.txt file rite, ur just getting the counts.

If u r so interested as not to use sort, better u use some loops to get the duplicated record & get the count using bash scripts.